# Make a foundation (library?) of instances to use within a program

Tags: c#, wpf, multiple-instances

I'm currently making a text game as a school project in C# (WPF). There were a few restrictions as to which structures and OOP principles have to be used(classes, inheritance, exceptions, ...) so I ended up creating 3 basic classes:

Scenery(should be Scene I quess)

```
{
public class Scenery
{
    /* VARIABLES */
    // used as reference for the creator, possibly for printout into label
    internal string _ID;
    public string ID { get { return _ID; } }

    // is written into text box after entering the scene
    // records changes the user made on the scene
    private string _phrase;
    internal string Phrase { get { return _phrase; } }

    // keys are IDs of game items within the scene
    // values are items themselves
    internal Dictionary<string, Item> _items;

    // keys are IDs of people within the scene
    // values are people themselves
    internal Dictionary<string, Person> _people;
    public Dictionary<string, Person> People { get { return _people; } }

    // directions in which the player can go
    internal Scenery[] _directions;
   /* CONSTRUCTORS */
   /* METHODS */
```

Person

```
{
public class Person
{
    /* VARIABLES */
    // basic identifier
    internal string _ID;
    public string ID { get { return _ID; } }

    // keys are keywords the person knows about
    // values are answers given when asking about a specific keyword
    internal Dictionary<string, string> _answers;
    public bool Answering { get { if (_answers == null) return false; else return true; } }

    // tree-like structure used to have a dialog with this person 
    internal Node _talk;
    public bool Talking { get { if (_talk == null) return false; else return true; } }

    // phrase to be written out when you start talking to the person
    // when reseting/looping is set to current _talk value
    private string _firstPhrase;
    public string FirstPhrase { get { return _firstPhrase; } }

    // talking interface window
    internal Dialog _dialog;
    public Dialog Dialog { get { return _dialog; } }
    /* CONSTRUCTORS */
   /* METHODS */
```

Item

```
{
public class Item
{
    /* VARIABLES */
    // identifier, used for writing out general messages and identifying user input
    private string _ID;
    public string ID { get { return _ID; } }

    // indicates if this item can be broken
    protected bool _breakable;

    // message to be written out after this item is broken
    protected string _breakPhrase;
    public string BreakPhrase { get { return _breakPhrase; } }

    // list of item got after breaking this item
    protected Dictionary<string, Item> _afterBreak;
    public Dictionary<string, Item> AfterBreak { get { return _afterBreak; } }
    public string AfterBreakPrint 
    {
        get
        {
            string toPrint = "";
            foreach (string key in _afterBreak.Keys) toPrint += '\n' + key;
            return toPrint;
        }
    }

    // indicates if this item can be investigated
    private bool _investigate;
    public bool Investigate { get { return _investigate; } }

    // reference to the investigation scene
    private Scenery _investigation;
    public Scenery Investigation { get { return _investigation; } }
   /* CONSTRUCTORS */
   /* METHODS */
```

There are a few subclasses such as PickableItem, UsableItem etc. The structure is rather complex (got Dictionary> and such in subclasses), but those are raltively easy to work with in methods, at least from my point view.

Now to the question: I got a separate class GameData, where I initialize all instances of the game - scenes, items, people and put then into right structures, plus there is a special public variable to use in one function to determine right item keys. Right now looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Markup;


namespace Textova_Hra
{
public static class GameData
{
    public static Scenery start; // starting location
    public static List<string> NA_ID_LIST = new List<string>(); // list of IDs in format 'x na y'
    // used in Addons -> GetTwoItems

    // Basically compiles the whole game returning the starting point
    // Declarations must be written from the inside out
    // Hra je pro češtinu, ID objektů zadávejte ve 4.pádě, jinak nebude správně fungovat!
    // First goes items and people "containing" only strings(and numbers)
    // Then goes lists of these items which you want to use in other items etc.
    // Last goes sceneries with directions arrays declared first, then scenery declarations, 
    // then filling corresponding directions arrays
    // Finaly the starting scene is saved into the start variable and returned
    // The game may begin!
    public static Scenery make_start()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Node> alisTalk1 = new Dictionary<string, Node>();
        Dictionary<string, Node> alisLoop = new Dictionary<string, Node>();
        Dictionary<string, string> alisAnswers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        alisAnswers.Add("cestu", "Tady zrovna žádné cesty nevedou.");
        Node alisTalk11 = new Node("Tak to je skvělé. Už musím běžet.");
        Node alisTalk12 = new Node("To je ale velice smutné. No nic, už budu muset jít.", alisLoop, true);
        alisTalk1.Add("dobře", alisTalk11);
        alisTalk1.Add("špatně", alisTalk12);

        Node alisTalk = new Node("Ahoj, jak se máš?", alisTalk1, false);
        alisLoop.Add("reset", alisTalk);
        Person Alis = new Person("Alis", alisAnswers, alisTalk);
        Dictionary<string, Person> start_people = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
        start_people.Add("Alis", Alis);
        Dictionary<string, Item> canBreak = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

        UsableItem hammer = new UsableItem("kladivo", "Sebrali jste pevné železné kladivo. Určitě se jen tak nerozbije.", -1, "", canBreak);
        Dictionary<string, Item> flowerVaseAfter = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
        Item flowerVase = new Item("váza s květinou", false, "Váza se s ohlušujícím třískotem rozbila na střepy, vypadly z ní mince. Květina leží uvadle na zemi.", flowerVaseAfter);
        Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, Item>> flowerChange = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, Item>>();
        Tuple<string, Item> flowervaset = new Tuple<string, Item>("vázu s květinou", flowerVase);
        flowerChange.Add("vázu", flowervaset);
        Dictionary<string, string> flowerPhrase = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        flowerPhrase.Add("vázu", "Dali jste květinu do vázy. Toto aranžmá místnost poněkud oživilo.");
        UsableItem flower = new UsableItem("květina", "Sebrali jste zvláštní namodralou květinu, poněkud uvadlou.", 1, "Květina je nyní ve váze.", flowerChange, flowerPhrase);
        PickableItem fragments = new PickableItem("střepy", "Sebrali jste hromádku střepů, třeba se  budou ještě k něčemu hodit.");
        PickableItem coins = new PickableItem("mince", "Sebrali jste pár zlatých mincí, kterým jste zkrátka nemohli ododlat.");
        Dictionary<string, Item> afterVase = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
        afterVase.AddMany(fragments, coins);
        flowerVaseAfter.AddRange(afterVase);
        Scenery[] vaseBack = new Scenery[4];
        Scenery vaseInvestigate = new Scenery("Zkoumáte vázu", "Ve váze vidíte několik mincí, ale hrdlo je příliš úzké, aby se daly vysypat.", vaseBack);
        Item vase = new Item("váza", true, "Váza se s ohlušujícím třískotem rozbila na střepy a vypadly z ní mince.", afterVase, vaseInvestigate);
        canBreak.Add("vázu", vase);
        canBreak.Add("vázu s květinou", flowerVase);
        Dictionary<string, Item> startItems = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
        startItems.Add("vázu", vase);
        startItems.Add("květinu", flower);
        startItems.Add("kladivo", hammer);
        Scenery[] startDirs = new Scenery[4];
        Scenery x = new Scenery("Úvod", "Vítejte v nové hře." + '\n' + "Jste v místnosti v malém domku. Mítnost je poloprázdná, je zde akorát malý stůl s vázou, vedle vázy leží květina a pod stolem někdo zapomněl kladivo.", startItems, start_people, startDirs);
        vaseBack[0] = x;
        start = x;

        return start;
    }
}
}
```

This inicializes 1 scene with 5 items in total and 1 person, that can talk and aswers simple question. I call it like this:

```
public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        /* GameData - static class containing declarations of all game instances + helpful variables
           method make_start inicializes all game instances and returns a starting point */
        current = GameData.make_start();
        // print out starting scene description
        tbStory.Text = current.Phrase;
        lblSceneName.Content = current.ID;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(MainWindow_Closed);
    }
```

The game itself is played within a wpf window with combobox used for user input, textbox for showing all the text and listbox with inventory. It all works fine, however the initialization of the game is really messy and untrackable.

I was wondering, if there is something like an instance manager (using Visual Studio 2012) or if it could be done in an easier way. I was also thinking about creating an instance manager for the game myself, making it into a usable engine, but there is not enough time for that and I'm not that good at programming to do that yet (working in C# 6 weeks only).

Any ideas?

PS: Is there a limit to how many constructors can a class have? My UsableItem class ended up with 24 of them covering all types of usableitems and it seems rather too much to me...

Comment: What do you mean with 'Instance manager'?

Comment: It sounds more like you want to write your setup files to an external format. XML sounds like a good bet, then you can edit the XML files to change the game structure and you don't need to recompile every time you want to change the game. You probably want to look into serialization, or even just have a game manager class which is responsible for reading the XML files and creating the initial game state. There are loads of XML reading tools in .NET (XmlDocument is good for interrogating the XML DOM with XPath queries - that way you don't need to sequentially read)

Comment: To further this - 24 constructors on one object is way too many (there may be objects with this many constructors in the framework, but there would be a good reason) - you can use the member initialiser syntax to initialise the object when you create it, without having to create a constructor for every combination of values you want. A constructor is responsible for setting up the base state of an object, but shouldn't be responsible for retrieving data (in all except the most trivial of circumstances)

Answer (score 0):

You can use initialization like so:

```
Dictionary<string, Node> list = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "One", new Node("One") },
    { "Two", new Node("Two") }
};
```

There are no limits to amount of constructors you add to a class as long as the signatures don't match (i.e. each constructor will have to have it's own unique set of input parameters).

```
public class Test1
{
    public Test1() { }
    public Test1(int i) { }
    public Test1(int i) { } /* Syntax error 'Test already defines a member called Test with the same parameter types */
}

public class Test2
{
    public Test2() { }
    public Test2(int i) { }
    public Test2(int i, int j) { }
}
```